# Create table shows ERROR 1005(HY000) errno 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

i tried to create tables as per given in my textbook in MySQL server as follows:

```
create table department
(dept_name      varchar(20), 
 building       varchar(15), 
 budget             numeric(12,2),
 primary key (dept_name)
);

create table course
(course_id      varchar(8), 
 title          varchar(50), 
 dept_name      varchar(20),
 credits        numeric(2,0),
 primary key (course_id),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department
);
```

the department table gets created, but an error

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.course' (errno: 150)
```

is displayed.

The queries seem very simple. And i am unable to find any mistake.
What can be the possible error that is preventing me to create the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing column name of parent table to which your child refer, while creating child table, do like below

```
create table department
(dept_name      varchar(20), 
 building       varchar(15), 
 budget             numeric(12,2),
 primary key (dept_name)
);

create table course
(course_id      varchar(8), 
 title          varchar(50), 
 dept_name      varchar(20),
 credits        numeric(2,0),
 primary key (course_id),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
);
```